# Ubuntu 12.10 wireless network disconnects with Samsung NP350E7C-S05NL

Tags: 12.10, wireless, laptop, samsung

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.1O on my new Samsung NP350E7C-S05NL laptop. The problem is that it wireless internet keeps disconnecting, after a few minutes working, and I have to continuously restart the internet connection.

When I do `lscpi -nn` I get:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: post result of `lsmod` & `sudo lshw -c network`